# MVC3 - Extending a Class and Updating the SQL Table

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I am using MVC3 and Entity Framework. I have a class called User with 20 different properties. I have already created a database and filled it with some data. I want to break out the Addresses property and make it it's own class.

```
namespace NameSpace.Domain.Entities
{
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    ...
    ...
    public string AddressOne { get; set; }
    public string AddressTwo { get; set; }
 }
}
```

I want to break out both Addresses like so

```
namespace NameSpace.Domain.Entities
{
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    ...
    ...
    public Addresses Addresses { get; set; }
 }
public class Addresses
{
    public string AddressOne { get; set; }
    public string AddressTwo { get; set; }
 }
}
```

HERE'S MY QUESTION:

Since I already have the data table filled with data, how can I update this in the Server Explorer?

Thanks ( if you need more info please let me know )

Comment: Which version of entity framework do you use?

Comment: @KMan - How do I run a codefirst migration if I HAVE NOT started my project as codefirst??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using EF code first 4.3 you can use the concept of migrations to achive what you want.

You will need to do a code based manual migration since you change is a bit to advanced for the framework to figure it out itselfe.

Further reading: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-code-based-migrations-walkthrough.aspx

Comment: I have a domain, test and ui layer. If I run 'Enable Migrations' in the PMC will it update to each of the necessary layers? Sorry, I am just hesitant to run a PMC command without knowing how to reverse it.

Comment: Or do I run this command on the Parent Solution. My project is organized like so

Solution.NameOfProject
   NameOfProject.Domain
   NameOfProject.Test
   NameOfProject.WebUI